# Storing the result of spark jobs in a hive table dynamically

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I will be running multiple spark jobs a day and I need to store the result of every spark job in a hive table dynamically after the job is done.

For example, let's say that the results of the spark jobs are like below

```
job1: a,344

job2: b,456

job3: c,6789
```

I need the results in a hive table like below

### Hive table: spark_results

```
spark_results.id   spark_results.value

    a                  344
    b                  456
    c                  6789
```

Is there any approach to do it?